# ComboBoxItem MouseEnter event not firing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, events

I've got the following sample code. Oddly enough, the MouseMove events fire properly, however when substituted with `MouseEnter`, nothing happens when the mouse moves over the `ComboBoxItem`. Any idea how to fix this? I actually need an event to occur when the user hovers over a `ComboBoxItem`, as well as another event when the hovering leaves the item.

```
var comboBoxItem1 = new ComboBoxItem();
var comboBoxItem2 = new ComboBoxItem();
cmb.Items.Add(comboBoxItem1);
cmb.Items.Add(comboBoxItem2);

comboBoxItem1.Content = "1";

comboBoxItem1.MouseMove += (s, args) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("1");
};

comboBoxItem2.Content = "2";
comboBoxItem2.MouseMove += (s, args) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("2");
};
```

**EDIT:**

```
                StackPanel spCondition = new StackPanel();
                spCondition.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

                ComboBox cmbValue1 = new ComboBox();
                cmbValue1.IsTextSearchEnabled = false;
                cmbValue1.IsEditable = true;
                cmbValue1.Width = 70;
                cmbValue1.LostFocus += cmbValue_LostFocus;
                cmbValue1.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += cmbValue_MouseLeftButtonDown;
                cmbValue1.SelectionChanged += cmbValue_SelectionChanged;

                Border border = new Border();
                border.Child = cmbValue1;

                spCondition.Children.Add(border);   

private void cmbValue_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
        cmb.Items.Clear();

        //Iterates through all virtual tables
        foreach (TableContainer table in parentTable.ParentVisualQueryBuilder.ListOpenUnjoinedTables)
        {
            ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
            item.MouseMove += item_MouseMove;

            if (table.IsVirtual == false)
            {
                item.Content = "[" + table.TableDescription + "]";
            }
            else
            {
                item.Content = "[" + table.View.Name + "]";
            }

            item.Tag = table;
            cmb.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try putting a breakpoint on MessageBox.Show line to see if it stops there?

Comment: @Yahya - Doesnt even enter the block!

Comment: "Windows events" would imply something else to me. Fixed your title.

Comment: Does the `cmb`'s parent have a background?

Comment: @Joulukuusi what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, I recall the parent `Grid` should have a `Background` property to send the `MouseEnter` notification. Could you post XAML of your control?

Comment: @Joulukuusi - Added the rest of the code. Controls are generated in code-behind dynamically

Comment: Works for me, just provided the parent window for `spCondition`. You might want to start a clean project just to test this out.

Comment: Just started a new project and it doesn't work either - could this be a Windows 8 issue?

Comment: Uh, I'm not sure, I don't have it. Just to be clear - you open the Combobox, then hover your mouse over "1" or "2", and nothing happens, right?

Comment: Are you sure you are adding items cmbValue1? Because in your example you are adding it to cmb.

Comment: Yes @Dilshod - that was just a quick example I made for Stack Overflow :)

Comment: And yes, thats right @Joulukuusi. And when I subsitute it for MouseMove, it works

Comment: could you provide the code in cmbValue_MouseLeftButtonDown()?

Comment: Could you upload your new project somewhere so I could test it on Windows 7?

Comment: @Joulukuusi - Rather, do you think you could upload your project for me to test under Windows 8? To be absolutely certain that I did nothing wrong myself

Comment: I think you deleting all your items on cmbValue_MouseLeftButtonDown() and adding them again. Could you just comment the code on cmbValue_MouseLeftButtonDown() and try?

Comment: @Joulukuusi - It works, but only because you've added `MouseMove`. My problem is that `MouseEnter` is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you are deleting the items in ComboBox in this code:

```
private void cmbValue_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
        cmb.Items.Clear();

        //Iterates through all virtual tables
        foreach (TableContainer table in parentTable.ParentVisualQueryBuilder.ListOpenUnjoinedTables)
        {
            ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
            item.MouseMove += item_MouseMove;

            if (table.IsVirtual == false)
            {
                item.Content = "[" + table.TableDescription + "]";
            }
            else
            {
                item.Content = "[" + table.View.Name + "]";
            }

            item.Tag = table;
            cmb.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Please try comment this code and run.

UPDATE:

You have this code to add items to the comoBox:

```
var comboBoxItem1 = new ComboBoxItem();
var comboBoxItem2 = new ComboBoxItem();
cmb.Items.Add(comboBoxItem1);
cmb.Items.Add(comboBoxItem2);

comboBoxItem1.Content = "1";

comboBoxItem1.MouseMove += (s, args) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("1");
};

comboBoxItem2.Content = "2";
comboBoxItem2.MouseMove += (s, args) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("2");
};
```

Change it with this code.

```
var comboBoxItem1 = new Label();//or use textBolck
var comboBoxItem2 = new Label();//or use textBolck
combo.Items.Add(comboBoxItem1);
combo.Items.Add(comboBoxItem2);

comboBoxItem1.Content = "1";

comboBoxItem1.MouseEnter += (s, args) =>
{
     MessageBox.Show("1");
};


comboBoxItem2.Content = "2";
comboBoxItem2.MouseEnter += (s, args) =>
{
     MessageBox.Show("2");
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm registering my MouseEnter event in there though

Comment: Yes you are right. First you are deleting all the items and adding new items to the comboBox. You will not be able to see the MessegeBox in this case.

Comment: But why does it work if I substitute MouseEnter with MouseMove? Same code, just a different event

Comment: The project you uploaded doesn't have any code in cmbValue_MouseLeftButtonDown(). Try to run the project you uploaded.

Comment: I tried running the project which was uploaded and it did not work when MouseMove was substituted with MouseEnter.

Comment: if I am understand you correctly, you want to see message box when MouseEnter on ComboBoxItem. Is that right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26560/discussion-between-dilshod-and-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Try using PreviewMouseEnter event. because I'm guessing there's some element that steals the event, so using a tunneling event should help.

Comment: PreviewMouseEnter doesnt seem to exist for ComboBoxItem